# What does "const [, xxx]" mean?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm learning how to use Nuxt to build generate a static blog, and I came across the piece of code bellow to create the page containing a list of posts:

```
<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData() {
      const resolve = require.context("~/content/", true, /\.md$/)
      const imports = resolve.keys().map((key) => {
        const [, name] = key.match(/\/(.+)\.md$/);
        return resolve(key);
      });
      return {
        posts: imports
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

I understand what it does: getting a list of all the markdown files and map their keys to the file's name, but I don't understand what `const [, name]` means, actually what the coma inside the array means.
can somebody explain it to me, please?

Thanks.

Noah

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values

Answer (score 1):

It's called [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring).

In your case `const [, name] = key.match(/\/(.+)\.md$/);` is the same as `const name = key.match(/\/(.+)\.md$/)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

It means take the second value from the array returned by `key.match` and assign it to the variable `name`

```js
const [a, b] = [123, 456];
console.log('a:', a, 'b:', b);   // a = 123, b = 456

const [, d] = [111, 222];
console.log('d:', d);            // d = 222
```